# Filter nested attributes with ruby mongoid gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, mongoid3, mongoid4

I have define the scope below (within my model) to help me filter out certain un-required nested data.

```
scope :active_inactive, -> { self.in({
      state: ["current"],
      "events.type" => [
        :active,
        :inactive,
      ]
    }).desc(:created_at) 
  }
```

When I run this I get results are contains other events like "in_progress" that this scope should not contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code should be rewritten into

```
scope :active_inactive, -> {
  self.where(:state.in => ["current"], :"events.type".in =>["active","inactive"]}).desc(:created_at) 
}
```

Comment: Almost there @vitali